# How to get list of all standard predefined macros in Clang

Tags: c, macos, macros, clang, llvm-clang

I can get list of Clang's compiler predefined macros with the following command in Terminal. ([Reference](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2011/12/c_c_tip_how_list_compiler_predefined_macros))

```
clang -dM -E -x c /dev/null
```

However, this list doesn't contain Standard Predefined Macros, such as `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, `__FUNCTION__`, etc. ([GCC version's list](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html))

- Q1. Is it possible to get the list of standard predefined macros in Clang in Terminal?
- Q2. If not, is there any complete list of standard predefined macros in Clang's documentation or something online?

My environment is macOS Sierra Version 10.12.1 (16B2555), Clang Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)

Comment: Maybe it is because those don't really have values until you're processing a non-empty file.  That's speculation, but `__func__` isn't a preprocessor object, and I could believe the same of `__FUNCTION__` for the same reason — the preprocessor doesn't know what a function is.  The value of `__LINE__` is undefined until the preprocessor is processing a line.  The value of `__FILE__` might only be set when `__LINE__` is set.  That said, it also misses out `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`.    But that's mostly guesswork, which is a main reason it is a comment, not an answer.